# How to check if a trigger is clicked?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, triggers

Well, I have a gameobject that is a trigger called Object A.

I want to know how to find out if the trigger was clicked. if I do

```
   void Update()
   {
       if( Input.GetMouseButton(0))
         {
               runthefunction();
         }
   }
```

then it just waits for me to click anywhere.

I want the `runthefunction()` function to run when I click on ObjectA (the trigger).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a trigger, use the function `OnTriggerEnter()`

```
void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    runthefunction();
}
```

See here for more info: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html